# MongoDB/Mongoose: many to many relationship

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, database

I have two Mongoose schemas `Post` and `Tag` and I want to design a many to many relationship between them. I'm wondering which one is the best solution for performances:

1. In both Tag and Post models keep an array with a reference to the models of the other schema (each Tag has many posts referenced in an array of ids and viceversa)
2. Keep the array of `Tag` ids only in the `Post` schema

The second solution seems easier to implement because when I edit the list of tags related to one post only one array has to be modified but at the same time might be less performant when getting all the posts that belongs to one tag

Answer (score 2):

> Keep the array of Tag ids only in the Post schema

I would definitely use this second solution which is more straightforward.

Unless you have exotic requirements, you shouldn't need to have each `Tag` explicitly tracking the `Post` references.  A array of `Post` references in  `Tag` documents would effectively be unbounded in size. This a usage pattern that tends to create storage fragmentation and/or performance issues for popular documents which frequently outgrow the [record padding](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/record-padding/) for their allocated record space.

On the other hand, the number of Tags used in a single Post is unlikely to change much over time and you can make this query performant by adding an index on the `Tag` array in your `Post` collection.